# Frequent kernel panics osx 10.9

Tags: macos, kernel-panic

I'm getting kernel panics more often than I'm comfortable with. I got one yesterday and one today, not sure the exact frequency before that, but I got at least a couple last week.

If anyone would care to look at the log it would be much appreciated.

I will keep posting logs here as they happen.

```
Anonymous UUID:       1E344B11-FFBA-CEC2-3EF3-9DBD32C79686

Wed Apr  2 11:40:26 2014
panic(cpu 1 caller 0xffffff8028adbe2e): Kernel trap at 0xffffff8028ad0c2f, type 14=page fault, registers:
CR0: 0x000000008001003b, CR2: 0x0000000000000010, CR3: 0x0000000041ff4075, CR4: 0x00000000000606e0
RAX: 0x0000000000000001, RBX: 0x0000000000000000, RCX: 0xffffff80381c88a0, RDX: 0xffffff80a1ce8088
RSP: 0xffffff80302dba98, RBP: 0xffffff80302dbac0, RSI: 0xffffff80a1ce8068, RDI: 0x0000000000000010
R8:  0xffffff80a1c55078, R9:  0xffffff80a1ce8068, R10: 0xffffff80302db8e0, R11: 0xffffffffffffff00
R12: 0xffffff8036518960, R13: 0xffffff803ede8f80, R14: 0xffffff802be80d40, R15: 0xffffff8028a7a9e4
RFL: 0x0000000000010202, RIP: 0xffffff8028ad0c2f, CS:  0x0000000000000008, SS:  0x0000000000000010
Fault CR2: 0x0000000000000010, Error code: 0x0000000000000000, Fault CPU: 0x1

Backtrace (CPU 1), Frame : Return Address
0xffffff80302db720 : 0xffffff8028a22fa9
0xffffff80302db7a0 : 0xffffff8028adbe2e
0xffffff80302db970 : 0xffffff8028af3326
0xffffff80302db990 : 0xffffff8028ad0c2f
0xffffff80302dbac0 : 0xffffff8028a7a4e4
0xffffff80302dbc30 : 0xffffff8028a83abe
0xffffff80302dbd70 : 0xffffff8028a827cd
0xffffff80302dbdf0 : 0xffffff8028aadaf8
0xffffff80302dbe20 : 0xffffff8028a619dd
0xffffff80302dbe50 : 0xffffff8028a26bf1
0xffffff80302dbe80 : 0xffffff8028a139f5
0xffffff80302dbef0 : 0xffffff8028a1e043
0xffffff80302dbf70 : 0xffffff8028ac976d
0xffffff80302dbfb0 : 0xffffff8028af3b46

BSD process name corresponding to current thread: Messages

Mac OS version:
13C64

Kernel version:
Darwin Kernel Version 13.1.0: Thu Jan 16 19:40:37 PST 2014; root:xnu-2422.90.20~2/RELEASE_X86_64
Kernel UUID: 9FEA8EDC-B629-3ED2-A1A3-6521A1885953
Kernel slide:     0x0000000028800000
Kernel text base: 0xffffff8028a00000
System model name: MacBookAir4,1 (Mac-C08A6BB70A942AC2)

System uptime in nanoseconds: 79088035452257
last loaded kext at 78956669031917: com.apple.driver.AppleIntelMCEReporter      104 (addr 0xffffff7faa99b000, size 49152)
last unloaded kext at 79040263461572: com.apple.driver.AppleIntelMCEReporter    104 (addr 0xffffff7faa99b000, size 32768)
loaded kexts:
com.avast.AvastFileShield       2.1.0
com.avast.PacketForwarder       1.4
com.Cycling74.driver.Soundflower        1.5.2
com.usboverdrive.driver.hid     3.0.1
org.virtualbox.kext.VBoxUSB     4.2.6
org.virtualbox.kext.VBoxDrv     4.2.6
at.obdev.nke.LittleSnitch       4052
com.apple.filesystems.afpfs     11.1
com.apple.nke.asp-tcp   8.0.1
com.apple.filesystems.smbfs     2.0.1
com.apple.driver.AppleHWSensor  1.9.5d0
com.apple.filesystems.autofs    3.0
com.apple.driver.AGPM   100.14.15
com.apple.iokit.IOBluetoothSerialManager        4.2.3f10
com.apple.driver.ApplePlatformEnabler   2.0.9d1
com.apple.driver.AppleMikeyHIDDriver    124
com.apple.driver.AudioAUUC      1.60
com.apple.iokit.IOUserEthernet  1.0.0d1
com.apple.driver.AppleHDA       2.6.0f1
com.apple.Dont_Steal_Mac_OS_X   7.0.0
com.apple.driver.AppleHWAccess  1
com.apple.driver.AppleMikeyDriver       2.6.0f1
com.apple.driver.AppleThunderboltIP     1.1.2
com.apple.driver.ACPI_SMC_PlatformPlugin        1.0.0
com.apple.driver.AppleLPC       1.7.0
com.apple.driver.AppleUpstreamUserClient        3.5.13
com.apple.driver.AppleSMCPDRC   1.0.0
com.apple.driver.AppleSMCLMU    2.0.4d1
com.apple.iokit.BroadcomBluetoothHostControllerUSBTransport     4.2.3f10
com.apple.driver.AppleBacklight 170.3.5
com.apple.driver.AppleMCCSControl       1.1.12
com.apple.driver.AppleIntelHD3000Graphics       8.2.4
com.apple.driver.AppleIntelSNBGraphicsFB        8.2.4
com.apple.driver.AppleUSBTCButtons      240.2
com.apple.driver.AppleUSBTCKeyboard     240.2
com.apple.AppleFSCompression.AppleFSCompressionTypeDataless     1.0.0d1
com.apple.AppleFSCompression.AppleFSCompressionTypeZlib 1.0.0d1
com.apple.BootCache     35
com.apple.driver.XsanFilter     404
com.apple.iokit.IOAHCIBlockStorage      2.5.1
com.apple.driver.AppleUSBHub    666.4.0
com.apple.driver.AirPort.Brcm4331       700.20.22
com.apple.driver.AppleAHCIPort  3.0.0
com.apple.driver.AppleUSBEHCI   660.4.0
com.apple.driver.AppleSmartBatteryManager       161.0.0
com.apple.driver.AppleRTC       2.0
com.apple.driver.AppleACPIButtons       2.0
com.apple.driver.AppleHPET      1.8
com.apple.driver.AppleSMBIOS    2.1
com.apple.driver.AppleACPIEC    2.0
com.apple.driver.AppleAPIC      1.7
com.apple.driver.AppleIntelCPUPowerManagementClient     216.0.0
com.apple.nke.applicationfirewall       153
com.apple.security.quarantine   3
com.apple.driver.AppleIntelCPUPowerManagement   216.0.0
com.apple.driver.AppleUSBHIDKeyboard    170.15
com.apple.driver.AppleHIDKeyboard       170.15
com.apple.security.SecureRemotePassword 1.0
com.apple.kext.triggers 1.0
com.apple.AppleGraphicsDeviceControl    3.4.35
com.apple.iokit.IOSerialFamily  10.0.7
com.apple.iokit.IOSurface       91
com.apple.driver.DspFuncLib     2.6.0f1
com.apple.vecLib.kext   1.0.0
com.apple.iokit.IOAudioFamily   1.9.5fc2
com.apple.kext.OSvKernDSPLib    1.14
com.apple.driver.IOPlatformPluginLegacy 1.0.0
com.apple.driver.IOBluetoothHIDDriver   4.2.3f10
com.apple.iokit.IOBluetoothFamily       4.2.3f10
com.apple.driver.AppleSMBusPCI  1.0.12d1
com.apple.driver.IOPlatformPluginFamily 5.7.0d10
com.apple.driver.AppleHDAController     2.6.0f1
com.apple.iokit.IOHDAFamily     2.6.0f1
com.apple.driver.AppleSMC       3.1.8
com.apple.iokit.IOBluetoothHostControllerUSBTransport   4.2.3f10
com.apple.driver.AppleBacklightExpert   1.0.4
com.apple.driver.AppleSMBusController   1.0.11d1
com.apple.iokit.IONDRVSupport   2.4.1
com.apple.iokit.IOGraphicsFamily        2.4.1
com.apple.iokit.IOSCSIArchitectureModelFamily   3.6.6
com.apple.driver.AppleThunderboltDPInAdapter    3.1.7
com.apple.driver.AppleThunderboltDPAdapterFamily        3.1.7
com.apple.driver.AppleThunderboltPCIDownAdapter 1.4.5
com.apple.driver.AppleUSBMultitouch     240.9
com.apple.iokit.IOUSBHIDDriver  660.4.0
com.apple.driver.AppleUSBMergeNub       650.4.0
com.apple.driver.AppleUSBComposite      656.4.1
com.apple.driver.CoreStorage    380
com.apple.driver.AppleThunderboltNHI    2.0.1
com.apple.iokit.IOThunderboltFamily     3.2.7
com.apple.iokit.IOUSBUserClient 660.4.2
com.apple.iokit.IO80211Family   630.35
com.apple.iokit.IONetworkingFamily      3.2
com.apple.iokit.IOAHCIFamily    2.6.5
com.apple.iokit.IOUSBFamily     675.4.0
com.apple.driver.AppleEFINVRAM  2.0
com.apple.driver.AppleEFIRuntime        2.0
com.apple.iokit.IOHIDFamily     2.0.0
com.apple.iokit.IOSMBusFamily   1.1
com.apple.security.sandbox      278.11
com.apple.kext.AppleMatch       1.0.0d1
com.apple.security.TMSafetyNet  7
com.apple.driver.AppleKeyStore  2
com.apple.driver.DiskImages     371.1
com.apple.iokit.IOStorageFamily 1.9
com.apple.iokit.IOReportFamily  23
com.apple.driver.AppleFDEKeyStore       28.30
com.apple.driver.AppleACPIPlatform      2.0
com.apple.iokit.IOPCIFamily     2.9
com.apple.iokit.IOACPIFamily    1.4
com.apple.kec.pthread   1
com.apple.kec.corecrypto        1.0
Model: MacBookAir4,1, BootROM MBA41.0077.B0F, 2 processors, Intel Core i5, 1.6 GHz, 4 GB, SMC 1.74f4
Graphics: Intel HD Graphics 3000, Intel HD Graphics 3000, Built-In, 384 MB
Memory Module: BANK 0/DIMM0, 2 GB, DDR3, 1333 MHz, 0x80CE, 0x4D34373142353737334448302D4348392020
Memory Module: BANK 1/DIMM0, 2 GB, DDR3, 1333 MHz, 0x80CE, 0x4D34373142353737334448302D4348392020
AirPort: spairport_wireless_card_type_airport_extreme (0x14E4, 0xE9), Broadcom BCM43xx 1.0 (5.106.98.100.22)
Bluetooth: Version 4.2.3f10 13477, 3 services, 15 devices, 1 incoming serial ports
Network Service: Wi-Fi, AirPort, en0
Serial ATA Device: APPLE SSD TS128C, 121,33 GB
USB Device: FaceTime Camera (Built-in)
USB Device: Hub
USB Device: USB 2.0 Hub
USB Device: Kinzu
USB Device: Keyboard Hub
USB Device: Apple Keyboard
USB Device: Apple Internal Keyboard / Trackpad
USB Device: BRCM20702 Hub
USB Device: Bluetooth USB Host Controller
USB Device: Hub
Thunderbolt Bus: MacBook Air, Apple Inc., 8.1
```

http://pastebin.com/U6usVd88

Comment: It shows Messages as the problem maker. Try disabling it.

Comment: I would start by disabling all of the third party kexts to see if that helps. If that does then reinstall them slowly one at a time to see if you can pin down which one or combo is at fault.

Comment: Use Terminal to run the command shown at http://pastebin.com/PjBZgSba then restart the Mac. You'll get verbose boot, verbose shut down and more importantly: the next .panic file will show more information in the backtrace.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> com.avast.AvastFileShield       2.1.0
>
> com.avast.PacketForwarder       1.4

Avast is possibly the worst Antivirus software available for OSX. Uninstall it, and its associated drivers, **according to the developer's instructions.** If the uninstaller still leaves traces of the software on the machine, then you need to manually unload and then delete the kernel extensions.

Additionally, you have made other low level system modifications which may be a catalyst. If the panics continue, uninstall the software associated with each driver in descending order until they cease.

**Most often, kernel panics are caused by third party kernel extensions which are either deprecated or incompatible**. [**In order to resolve them**](http://www.thexlab.com/faqs/kernelpanics.html), these extensions must be removed.

Comment: I'd agree with njboot here. I tried Avast on a test machine. Fully updated and a fresh install and it caused performance issues and numerous errors in my logs with the occasional crash. If you do a search for Avast for Mac you'll see dozens of similar issues. Top experts at Apple Discussion forums always say the same thing... Remove Avast. As an alternative to Avast try ClamXav on the Mac App Store. I've never heard of it causing a single issue & it only runs on demand or on schedule, but not in realtime which you don't really need on a Mac.

Answer (score 1):

Regardless of Messages being identified as a possible suspect, I find that highly unlikely, as that is Apple software running on Apple hardware. I'd be willing to bet that it is your [Avast software](http://www.google.com/search?q=avast+kernel+panic&ie=UTF-8&oe=UTF-8&hl=en&client=saf), which should only be necessary if you often use the machine in a Windows network with Windows users. Avast on OS X really has no benefit to the Mac user, and only helps protect other platforms from Windows viruses that may have entered into your own files. Surprisingly, Avast includes an [uninstaller](http://download.cnet.com/Avast-Free-Antivirus/3001-2239_4-75451160.html?spi=0b20d311aff322b206b12828dc3969cb) with their installer, if you'd like to remove it to see if the kernel panics cease.

Answer (score 0):

[Google has admitted](http://www.slashgear.com/google-admits-macbook-chrome-crash-bug-29236464/) there is a well know bug with the graphic drivers in MacBooks using Chrone. Other applications such as Firefox have the [same problem](http://www.brendangregg.com/blog/2014-05-23/osx-10.9.3-is-toxic.html) with hardware acceleration.

In my case I solved these panics disabling hardware acceleration in Firefox (Preferences->Advanced->General) and [Thunderbird](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/questions/1012145). I am not using Chrone.